# Defining a Paint style, color, etc in XML?

Tags: android, xml, coding-style, paint

I'm doing some rather basic drawing in an app I am working on, and am wondering about the 'proper' way to handle defining the Paint's attributes, such as color, etc.  With strings, styles, menus, layouts, etc being separated from app logic and defined in XML, I was wondering about how to (if possible) define a Paint 'style' in XML in much the same way.

I've done a number of searches and have come up empty, which may be the answer, but was wondering about other approaches than, say:

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setColor(0x80808080);
```

Thanks,

Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no possibility to define a paint style in an Android resource XML file. What you can do though is to define the necessary values (integers, colors, etc.) in a resource XML and load them to your Paint object later manually. It is still hardcoded somehow, but at least you can define colors etc. in your resource file once and use them at different locations later. :-)

Comment: So for instance, something like the following to set the color of the Paint?  mPaint.setColor((int)R.styles.lineColor);

Comment: I meant using something like mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yourcolor)); (I guess your code will not work because setting a style id integer as a color value does not seem logically to me)